# How to extract value between # and space in textarea value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following textarea code.

```
<textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
```

I need to get the value of the textarea and track the message content and extract out keywords that is hashed (#).

### Example if the message is as below

### This is my message #message #lol #haha

When i click on submit button. The keywords that i should get is 'lol and 'haha' and 'message'.

I am using jquery. Can anyone give me some advices on how to go about doing so?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at regular expressions.

Comment: Split at whitespaces into words, then check the words for their first character

Comment: So you have `#message #lol #haha` — why isn’t `message` part of the results?

Comment: What have *you* tried? And I wouldn't use regular expressions. I'd split all words (by space) into an array, check each item if the first char is `#`, then add those items to an array called keywords.

Comment: Well, since there are so many naysayers: I would use regular expressions too, assuming `message` is okay: `value.match(/#\w+/g)` as opposed to `value.split(' ').filter(function(x) { return x.charAt(0) === '#'; })` (That one needs ES5 array extensions, too.)

Comment: how do i use regular expression? is not sure about regular expression usage in javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per comment, split at whitespaces, then uses [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) by checking first character.

Javascript

```
var message = "This is my message #message #lol #haha";

var wanted = message.split(/\s/).reduce(function (previous, word) {
    if (word.charAt(0) === "#") {
        previous.push(word.slice(1));
    }

    return previous;
}, []).join(" ");

console.log(wanted);
```

Output

```
message lol haha
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/4T4ac/)

Alternatively using [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Javascript

```
var message = "This is my message #message #lol #haha";

var wanted = message.split(/\s/).filter(function (word) {
    return word.charAt(0) === "#";
}).map(function (word) {
    return word.slice(1);
}).join(" ");

console.log(wanted);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/WpPAa/)

Note: all of the above `Array` methods require a shim on pre ECMA5 browsers, available on their respective MDN pages or the use of [es5_shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)

Other alternatives, *if you so desired*, would be to use [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) (which would require a shim), [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) or [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) to perform the looping of elements and [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the relevant ones.

Comment: Might be worth saying that `Array.prototype.reduce` is not available in IE8-. +1 for use of it though, it is good for so much but rarely my first thought.

Comment: Indeed. For older browsers there is a shim on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) page or the full [ES5 Shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)

Comment: I have added to the example, the use of `filter` and `map`, as nobody else demonstrated (thought it had been). Does this satisfy?

Comment: No problem. Thanks for coming back and undoing your down vote, in fact thanks for commenting that you did down vote, so many that don't.

Answer (score 1):

```
// You split the words with the space
var arrayContainingEveryWords = $("#message").val().split(" "); 
var desiredWords = [];

// For each word within the text area
for (var i = 0; i < arrayContainingEveryWords.length; i++) 
{
    var word = arrayContainingEveryWords[i];

    // If the first letter of the word is a #
    if (word.charAt(0) == "#")
    {
        // Add the word (minus the #) to an array
        desiredWords.push(word.slice(1));
    }
}

console.log(desiredWords);
```

Comment: What happened to the [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) keywords?

Comment: I would like to give you +1 for using a `for` loop, but the code is not fully working (missing).

Comment: I've added the return values, I assume that's what you meant was missing.

Comment: As it is not a function you do not need `return` just `console.log(desiredWords)`. You also need to initiate `desiredWords = []` :)

Comment: Do we really need to initiate the array?

Comment: Yes, otherwise JS will throw an error when it tries to use `push` which is an array method.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "This is my message #message #lol #haha";
// or var str = $('#message').val(); 
var words = str.split(' ');

words = $(words).map(function (i,v) {
    if(v.indexOf('#') === 0)return v.replace("#",'');
}).get();

console.log(words);

//output `==>` ["message", "lol", "haha"]
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/vTpSk/2/

Answer (score 1):

Use a [*RegExp*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) like `/(?:\s|^)#([^\s]+)/g` with [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), i.e. space or start of line, then `#`, then non-space.

```
var m = 'This is my message #message #lol #haha'.match(/(?:\s|^)#([^\s]+)/g);
// [" #message", " #lol", " #haha"]
```

Then you can loop over these with your preferred loop, e.g. with [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

```
var i, found = [], u;
for (var i = 0; i < m.length; ++i) {
    u = m[i];
    if (u.charAt(1) === '#') u = u.slice(2);
    else u = u.slice(1);
    found.push(u);
}
found; // ["message", "lol", "haha"]
```

---

With the same *RegExp*, because of how I set up the capture groups, you can strip and catch at the same time using [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```
var found = [], str = 'This is my message #message #lol #haha';
str = str.replace(
    /(?:\s|^)#([^\s]+)/g,
    function (m, keyword) {
        found.push(keyword);
        return '';
    }
);
str;   // "This is my message"
found; // ["message", "lol", "haha"]
```

A slight modification here could also let you capture them using `replace` without removing them, (`return m` in the *function* or just keep another copy of the string).

Answer (score 1):

You can use one simple regular expression: `\B#\w+`.

```
var keywords = 'This is my message #message #lol #haha'.match(/\B#\w+/g);
```

And then remove the `#`s if need be:

```
keywords = keywords.map(function(k) { return k.substring(1); });
// or jQuery, for compatibility:
keywords = $.map(keywords, function() { return this.substring(1); });
```

Or use a loop:

```
var keywords = [];
var keyword;
var re = /\B#(\w+)/g;

while(keyword = re.exec('This is my message #message #lol #haha')) {
    keywords.push(keyword[1]);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `.split('#')` on the string to get an array of words, then use `.trim()` on each item to get rid of the space.