# Highlight Text in textarea when a Hashtag typed followed by one or more character

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to be able to let the user wile typing in the text area if he typed a hash-tag followed by one or more character as he type the text get highlighted till he hits space.

The thing is i want to achieve something like Facebook's new hash-tag feature, I've done the logic the coding but still not able to achieve it visually.

The approach i tried is by using Jquery as follows:

```
<textarea id="txtArea">Here is my #Hash</textarea>

$("#txtArea").onkeyup(function(){

var result = $("#txtArea").match(/ #[\w]+/g);

//result = '#Hash'
});
```

But i couldn't complete & i don't know where to go from here so any solution, advice, plugin that i could use i'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe there is any way to highlight words (other than one single highlight) within a basic `textarea` as it does not accept markup, you could turn the `textarea` into a small Rich Text editor, but that seems a little overcomplicated. I would probably go for similar approach to the editor here on SO, and have a preview window below so that you can see what is being marked. You could use something like this, of course you may want to change how it works a little to suit your exact needs. It should at least give you some ideas.

CSS

```
#preview {
    height: 2em;
    width: 12em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}
.hashSymbol {
    color: #f90;
}
```

HTML

```
<textarea id="userInput"></textarea>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

Javascript

```
/*jslint maxerr: 50, indent: 4, browser: true */

(function () {
    "use strict";

    function walkTheDOM(node, func) {
        func(node);
        node = node.firstChild;
        while (node) {
            walkTheDOM(node, func);
            node = node.nextSibling;
        }
    }

    function getTextNodes(element) {
        var nodes = [];

        walkTheDOM(element, function (node) {
            if (node.nodeType === 3) {
                nodes.push(node);
            }
        });

        return nodes;
    }

    function escapeRegex(string) {
        return string.replace(/[\[\](){}?*+\^$\\.|]/g, "\\$&");
    }

    function highlight(element, string, classname) {
        var nodes = getTextNodes(element),
            length = nodes.length,
            stringLength = string.length,
            rx = new RegExp("\\B" + escapeRegex(string)),
            i = 0,
            index,
            text,
            newContent,
            span,
            node;

        while (i < length) {
            node = nodes[i];
            newContent = document.createDocumentFragment();
            text = node.nodeValue;
            index = text.search(rx);
            while (index !== -1) {
                newContent.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text.slice(0, index)));
                text = text.slice(index + stringLength);
                span = document.createElement("span");
                span.className = classname;
                span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(string));
                newContent.appendChild(span);
                index = text.search(rx);
            }

            newContent.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
            node.parentNode.replaceChild(newContent, node);
            i += 1;
        }
    }

    function addEvent(elem, event, fn) {
        if (typeof elem === "string") {
            elem = document.getElementById(elem);
        }

        function listenHandler(e) {
            var ret = fn.apply(null, arguments);

            if (ret === false) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
            }

            return ret;
        }

        function attachHandler() {
            window.event.target = window.event.srcElement;

            var ret = fn.call(elem, window.event);

            if (ret === false) {
                window.event.returnValue = false;
                window.event.cancelBubble = true;
            }

            return ret;
        }

        if (elem.addEventListener) {
            elem.addEventListener(event, listenHandler, false);
        } else {
            elem.attachEvent("on" + event, attachHandler);
        }
    }

    function emptyNode(node) {
        while (node.firstChild) {
            node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
        }
    }

    function toPreviewHighlight(e, to) {
        if (typeof to === "string") {
            to = document.getElementById(to);
        }

        var value = e.target.value,
            tags = value.match(/\B#\w+/g) || [],
            index = tags.length - 1,
            lookup = {},
            fragment,
            length,
            tag;

        while (index >= 0) {
            tag = tags[index];
            if (!tag.length || tag === "#" || tag.charAt(0) !== "#" || lookup[tag]) {
                tags.splice(index, 1);
            } else {
                lookup[tag] = true;
            }

            index -= 1;
        }

        fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        fragment.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
        index = 0;
        length = tags.length;
        while (index < length) {
            tag = tags[index];
            highlight(fragment, tag, "hashSymbol");
            index += 1;
        }

        emptyNode(to);
        to.appendChild(fragment);
    }

    addEvent("userInput", "keyup", function (e) {
        toPreviewHighlight(e, "preview");
    });
}());
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/XjmuK/)

This code is slightly modified from other questions and answers here on SO (resusing code is good)

[if text contains '@' change color of '@'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191076/if-text-contains-change-color-of/17191144#17191076)

[How to extract value between # and space in textarea value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176463/how-to-extract-value-between-and-space-in-textarea-value)

[Using JavaScript, I want to use XPath to look for the presence of a string, then refresh the page based on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199598/using-javascript-i-want-to-use-xpath-to-look-for-the-presence-of-a-string-then/17200080#17200080)

Comment: Why not use a div or something with #contantEditable?

Comment: The question was about highlighting in a `textarea` and that is what this answer primarily addresses. Feel free to give an answer showing how you could do it with your suggestion, which I also stated "a small Rich Text editor" i.e. using [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable).

Comment: Please Can you make it supported Any Unicode like Arabic characters 
#أخبار